# Maven - skip plugin if property is empty/null

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, pom.xml, maven-profiles

I want to obtain the following behavior: when I specify a value for the property "my.prop", I want the dependency and clean plugins to be executed. If a value is not specified for that property, I want them to be skipped.

I created "my.prop" like this:

```
<properties>
    <my.prop></my.prop>
</properties>
```

Then I read that profile activation works only for system properties, so I deleted the above and used the surefire plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <my.prop></my.prop>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I tried using profiles, like this:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <skipDependecyAndCleanPlugins>false</skipDependecyAndCleanPlugins>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>skip-dependency-and-clean-plugins</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>my.prop</name>
                <value></value>
                <!-- I also tried:  <value>null</value> without success.-->
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <skipDependecyAndCleanPlugins>true</skipDependecyAndCleanPlugins>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Later, for each plugin I do something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>${skipDependecyAndCleanPlugins}</skip>
    </configuration>
    ....
</plugin>
```

But the plugins are still executed...

How can I determine Maven to skip the executions of the plugins when "my.prop" is empty/null?

Comment: First quenstion: Why do you need such behaviour? Can you elaborate a little bit more what you like to achieve?

Comment: I'm working with an Oxygen XML Editor plugin. And what I want is that, if a user specifies the path to [OXY_DIR]/plugins, the plugin be deployed there automatically. For this purpose, those 2 plugins have to be executed. If the user leaves "my.prop" empty, then the plugins dealing with deploying the plugin should not be executed.

Comment: I would suggest to use a profile and **NOT** a property. So you can simply define on command line `mvn -Pxyz install` or leave it.

Comment: this seems an option... you could add it to your answer... I might accept it soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use the activation in the following form:

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>debug</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

The above means you can define any value for debug which means `-Ddebug` is enough.

An empty value can't be defined a pom file cause `<value></value>` is equivalent to `<value/>` which means the same as not defined.

**Update:**

I would suggest to use a profile and NOT a property. So you can simply define on command line mvn -Pxyz install or leave it.

Comment: if I pass the value using -Dmy.prop, di I need to declare it somehow in pom.xml... what should I do with the first 2 snippets I posted? do I need any of them?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that directly addresses the OP's *original* request: the ability to skip a plugin's execution if a POM property (not a system property) `my.prop` is not defined. This solution relies on the [Apache Maven Help Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/). It is a kludge, but given Maven's paucity of expression prowess, this is about the best you're gonna get. At least it relies on a well-known, hopefully-maintained plugin, and should work 100% of the time. Oh, and it may make your head explode. Or make you cry. Or both. You've been warned.

1. First declare the latest version of the Maven Help Plugin in the `<build><pluginManagement>` section:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.0</version>
</plugin>
```

2. Then add this "secret sauce" in the `<build><plugins>` section, which will check to see if `my.prop` is defined:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>set-is-skip-true-or-prefixed</id>
      <phase>validate</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>regex-property</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <name>is-skip</name>
        <value>_${my.prop}</value>
        <regex>_\$\{my.prop\}</regex>
        <replacement>true</replacement>
        <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>set-is-skip</id>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>regex-property</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <name>is-skip</name>
        <value>${is-skip}</value>
        <regex>_.*</regex>
        <replacement>false</replacement>
        <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

3. Now you have a POM property (not a system property) named `is-skip`, which you can use in any later phase to disable a plugin—provided that plugin has a `<skip>` or similar option taking a Boolean value. If `my.prop` is not defined at all, `is-skip` will be set to `true`; otherwise `is-skip` will be set to `false`.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>foobar-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>foo</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>foo</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <skip>${is-skip}</skip>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

There is one caveat: don't define `my.prop` at all, even to the empty string, or this solution will consider it defined and set `is-skip` to `false`. Setting `is-skip` to `true` if `my.prop` is set but empty would require an additional regex evaluation clause above. For my use case I didn't need it, as an empty `my.prop` isn't valid and I didn't define `my.prop` at all in the parent POM.

I'll leave it to you to understand how it works (my head exploded already when I was writing it), but I'll be happy to answer any questions.

In step #2 above, **be sure and put the two regex evaluations in different phases**, such as `validate` and `initialize` as used here. The reason is because Maven gets confused if you mix in the same plugins in in the same phase a child POM, and may scramble the execution order. (See [MNG-5987](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5987).) My kludge of a solution relies on the order of evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `my.prop` property in plugin's configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>${my.prop}</skip>
    </configuration>
    ....
</plugin>
```

Now when you execute:

```
mvn ... -Dmy.prop=true
```

then plugin will be skipped

Comment: not really... my.prop is supposed to contain a file path... a typical example of bad property name, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. You can achieve what you described by using the `!my.prop` syntax in profile activation.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <skip>${skipDependecyAndCleanPlugins}</skip>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>skip-dependency-and-clean-plugins</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>!my.prop</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
      <skipDependecyAndCleanPlugins>true</skipDependecyAndCleanPlugins>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

According to [Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), the `skip-dependency-and-clean-plugins` profile will be activated when the system property `my.prop` is not defined at all.